# Woocommerce API - Requests from my own front-end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

So I have looked for any answers/documentation on this topic with little luck. It seems like something that would be relatively common. I have a new site design for a WordPress woocommerce-powered site. The entirety of the system doesn't really function like a standard woocommerce shop. At least not interface-wise. So the frontend and all templates will need to be custom. However what I was thinking of doing is using a JS framework, and interacting directly with the Woocommerce API. Here is my concern:

I generate API keys for Woocommerce, and will have to include that in my requests to the backend (must be read/write permissions). So if these requests are made from the front-end, any bozo can simply look at their network tab and take my API keys. What stops them from then making any request they want to my site? Deleting Products? Getting User Data?

I guess I'm just not clear on how that is supposed to work and am unclear from what I see in the docs. Or is this functionality simply not the intention of the API, and it exists primarily to allow your site to interface with third party applications?

Any insights into using the Woocommerce API here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah I know that I could build my application's backend myself using built-in woocommerce functionality. I disagree that a REST API is solely for external consumption. A front-end javascript application - using something like Angular let's say - you would want to interact with your site's back-end solely as an API. Lots of web applications work this way. with a javascript 'service' consuming a de-coupled backend. THat's the kind of solution I'm wondering about for a portion of my site, where the frontend functions as a standalone app. I know that's not well understood in WP

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I ran into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin [Backbone client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) within wordpress, all you need to do is `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );` into your code to get it in your front end at `window.wp.api`.

You could then get posts like this

```
const posts = new wp.api.collections.Posts();
posts.on('sync', () => console.log(`${posts.length} posts synced`))
posts.fetch();
```

Under the hood this uses a `X-WP-Nonce` http header, and it happens to expire, and if that happens the page needs to reload to get a new `X-WP-Nonce`. No need to generate api keys for this to work.

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score -1):

If your wordpress site is in http server, you'll need to used a certain kind of encoding to encode your parameters(key and secret) i.e. HMAC-SHA1

If your wordpress site is in https server, its already encoded and secure. Then just pass the key and secret as parameters.

So in both cases no one can know your key and secret. Go through the documentation for exact JS code.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662665/enable-woocommerce-on-http/48678525)

Comment: best plugin for front end REST API with woo-commerce mlmtrees.com/product/woocommerce-b2c-rest-api